# Replace values in each cell based on other rows using lambda and apply i python

Tags: python, lambda, data-science, apply

I'm trying to replace the values in each cell with 1 if the value is equal to highest value in other columns in the row.

[This is the data i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A2up.png)

[This is where i want to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBjvi.png)

This is what i tried so far:

```
df_ref['max'] = df_ref.max(axis=1)
df_ref['col1'] = df_ref.col1.apply(lambda x:1 if (x==df_ref['max']) else 0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of object is df_ref?

Comment: its a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're almost there, you don't need the max column just apply it within your lambda function and use `.any()`, you also need your process within a loop over columns:

```
import pandas as pd

#data
d = {'col1': [0, 1, 0.170531, 0.170533, 0.170531],
 'col2': [0, 0, 0.005285, 0.005285, 0.005285],
 'col3': [0, 0, 0.047557, 0.047557, 0.047557],
 'col4': [1, 0, 0.482381, 0.003104, 0.482381],
 'col5': [0, 0, 0.003104, 0.482458, 0.003104],
 'col6': [0, 0, 0.001109, 0.001108, 0.001109]}

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

#list of columns
columns = df.columns.tolist()

#loop over columns
for col in columns:
    #change to 1 if value equals to the max in that row
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x:1 if (x==df.max(axis=1)).any() else 0)

print(df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     0     0     0     1     0     0
1     1     0     0     0     0     0
2     0     0     0     1     0     0
3     0     0     0     0     1     0
4     0     0     0     1     0     0
```